# Android Studio : how to create hotkey to clear logcat?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

How to create hotkey to clear logcat in Android Studio.
I also look in file/setting/keymap but there is no command to clear logcat.

Sometimes I want want to see logs of previous launch too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Android Studio preference/keymap. Search for "Clear all" then assign your key.

[image]
However, you need to click/focus on the logcat anyway. PS. I have installed plugin

> Key Promoter

This plugin help me use and assign new hotkeys alot

Answer (score 25):

You can clear Logcat on every time you run the app.
For android Studio:
Go to 
Run > Edit configuration > Logcat tab > check "Clear Log before launch."